# as3 multitouch - how to do single touch only?

Tags: actionscript-3, touch, multi-touch

I have a childs game that i am writting and i need to be able to do 1 single touch only.

My sons knuckles keep touching the screen and it goes mad..

I can't work out how to do single touch only ??

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` or `TouchEvent.TOUCH_END`, so that it dispatches the event when the user is about to touch or remove the finger from the screen.

Comment: Hi Moorthy, I do use those events but it allows multiple touches

Comment: kindly ensure you were setting the `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;`

Comment: yes its set to Touch_point but i only need 1 touch

Comment: You could try using MouseEvents instead of TouchEvents

Comment: If you dont want to listen for that event then remove it once it receives or else do like what loxxy said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most touch screens will see standard mouse events as 'touch' events. This is ideal for single touch in my experience. Build your app as you normally would, and all the standard cursor data should pass. This also allows for easy testing. If this is for a mobile app or iOS it may get picky and will likely require the TouchEvent class... The touch listeners are typically listening to ALL touch events which means it WILL notice 'multitouch' even if you're app isnt intended for it.

Build your app using MouseEvents for testing purposes and replace with TouchEvents...

There are a few translations to be aware of, for example `MOUSE_DOWN` = `TOUCH_BEGIN` which I'm sure you know by now, and with the right listeners it shouldn't be too hard to manage. Make sure to remove listeners when they are not needed.

Read about the different ways flash handles touch events: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's your app, make it not go mad with multi touch.

Why not a set a flag (a boolean variable) to keep track of touch or no touch.

Check the status of the variable to see if it is already true & then handle the event.

Comment: I thought there would be a better way to only use single touch than settings a boolean, if not than i'll try it that way

Comment: No need. Just use MouseEvent instead,  as long as the mouse (or touch) is down, it will not dispatch any other mouse events.  At least on android, haven't tested on iOS but I'm pretty sure it's the same